# Как не полностью задвинуть блок за пределы экрана?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animation

Ребята мне необходимо задвинуть блок с контентом за пределы экрана, но не полностью, а оставить 50 пикселей. Я пробую это делать вот так:

```
var scw = $( window ).width() - 50;
    $(".contentlayer").toggle("slide", {direction: "right"}, function(){
        $(".contentlayer").css({"margin-left": scw+"px", "display":"block"});
    });
```

В представленном мною примере блок "contentlayer" здвигается за пределы экрана, но затем я его на 50 пикселей как бы выдвигаю.

Получается скачек. Возможно есть другой способ сделать то что мне нужно, так как все-таки toggle работает как спойлер, присваивая блоку display none

**Для наглядности предлагаю посмотреть сайт: [перейти на сайт]**[1](http://m.%D0%BC%D1%86%D1%83%D0%BD.%D1%80%D1%84) Здесь нажав на кнопку меню слева будет срабатывать та анимация, которой посвящен данный вопрос

Comment: Добавьте HTML и CSS в вопрос

Comment: ну тут нет никакого html  и ксс.  .contentlayer имеет ширину 100%. высота зависит от контента.

Comment: Есть вариант сделать вот так:
    $( ".contentlayer" ).animate({
      "margin-left": "100px",
    }, 500, function() {

    });

Но возможно есть способ сделать плавнее?

Comment: easing function только. Да у вас и сейчас неплохо